# JQueryUI droppable hover class bug on scaled target

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, scale, droppable

When droppable element is scaled, JQueryUI incorrectly adds/remove hover class to the elements: two 'tr' elements of scaled table get this class at once.
Is there any way to avoid this?

PS
[bug ticket here](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15277#comment:3)

[dirty fix here(codepen)](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/mXNVJm?editors=0010)

[or here(github)](https://github.com/YuriGor/jquery-ui/commit/fc32a34b5a5be8d4272c62136621c78717fa972b)

```js
$('div').draggable();
$('tr').droppable({hoverClass:"highlight"});
```

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px;
  border:1px solid rgba(200,0,0,.6);
}
table {
  transform:scale(0.5);
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding:5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,150,0.3);
}
tr.highlight td {
  background: rgba(150,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>grab me and drag over the table</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11111111111111111111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222222222222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333333333333333333333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11111111111111111111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222222222222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333333333333333333333</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `transform:scale()` change the element pixel ratio not its actual pixel on DOM

so why not just reduce the `font-size` and `padding` of `td` instead of using `transform`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('div').draggable();
$('tr').droppable({
  hoverClass: "highlight"
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(200, 0, 0, .6);
}

table {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.3);
  font-size: 10px;
}

tr.highlight td {
  background: rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>grab me and drag over the table</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11111111111111111111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222222222222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333333333333333333333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11111111111111111111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222222222222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333333333333333333333</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Snippet in my question is just live  example of reproduced bug. In real life i have huge editable diagram of database with pan and zoom. So i need exactly what I asked: the workaround to avoid this bug, but not a suggestion to redesign an app.